# Firebug console info conversion to function()

Tags: javascript, function, console, firebug

javascript source:

```
KT_initKeyHandler(b)
```

firebug console:

```
KT_initKeyHandler(b=keydown charCode=0, keyCode=90)
```

javascript function:

```
KT_initKeyHandler(?)
```

**Example:**

javascript source:

```
KT_event(b,c)
```

firebug console:

```
KT_event(b=Object { k=90, m=0, t="1"}, c=0)
```

javascript function:

```
KT_event([k=122, m=0, t="1"],c=1)
```

Comment: What is your question at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can create object constants:

```
KT_event({ k: 122, m: 0, t: "1" } , 1);
```

That will call the function "KT_event" with two parameters: the first is an object with three properties, and the second is a number.  If the function is declared as you wrote:

```
function KT_event(b, c) { ... }
```

Then "b" will be bound to the object and "c" to the numeric value 1.

Comment: i know, but i need help : KT_initKeyHandler(b)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really understand what it is you need help with; I had to guess. Can you try again?  I can read a little French or Spanish or Italian (just a little :-)